# Shrinking inner html elements with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

is it possible to shrink and grow child HTML elements with just CSS. Here is an example below, I want to see how others would approach this. I have seen solutions with JQuery however wanted to know there is an easier way to do this.

```
<div class="your_custom_styling_here_for_resizing">
    <div style="width: 400px; height: 400px; display: flex;">
      <div style="height: 100px; background: #333333; flex: 1;"></div>
      <div style="background: #cccccc; flex: 1;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your elements are shrinking and growing based on CSS properties. If you want some dynamic behavior, you need to use Javascript/jQuery

Comment: So the only way you're aware of to scale this down from the parent level (your_custom_styling_here_for_resizing) is using JS/JQuery? That is without having to explicitly state in the child styling

Answer (score 0):

An easier solution would be to create a class for those styles instead of using inline CSS, and for the new styles, then adding / removing / changing just classes from jquery.

Comment: the reason for using inline styles here was to quickly represent i.e. an external CSS file. No other reason, simply quicker.  I can not copy the project here due to NDA. The child styling for this example remains un touched. The solution I am curious of is parent level.

Answer (score 0):

You want a child element to scale to the parent elements dimensions? If you do then just do the following:

```css
.parent {
  border: 5px solid red;
}

.child {
  width: inherit;
  height: auto;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Expand or shrink your screen to see me scale to my parent</div>
</div>
```

}

Comment: Okay you have put a border around the parent elements. Now imagine the child with width 100px and height 284px. Now from the parent resize the children elements in proportion to the given values, don't change the children values.